# Issue on External json file for creating basic bubble chart using d3 js

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, d3.js

I am currently working on a small project where I need to use a bubble chart exactly described in this blog [See it here](http://bl.ocks.org/phuonghuynh/54a2f97950feadb45b07). I want its content to be dynamic, so what I did is to modify it so it would get content from a json page. As I code I encounter an error exactly described [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35935495/using-external-json-file-for-creating-bubble-chart-using-d3js). I followed the solution from it but I got an error its says "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'items' of undefined". I can't comment on the issue since I dont have enough reputation so I created a new question instead.

here is the original code from D3(index.js, ellipsis to shorten code):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var bubbleChart = new d3.svg.BubbleChart({
supportResponsive: true,
size: 600,
...
data: {
  items: [
    {text: "Java", count: "236"},
    {text: ".Net", count: "382"},
    {text: "Php", count: "170"},        
    ...
    {text: "Something", count: "170"},
  ],
  eval: function (item) {return item.count;},
  classed: function (item) {return item.text.split(" ").join("");}
},
plugins: [
  {
    ...
  },
  {
    ...
  }]  });
});
```

Here is my updated code as suggested from the link I mentioned earlier:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
d3.json("http://json/path/", function (json) {  
var bubbleChart = new d3.svg.BubbleChart({
    supportResponsive: true,
    size: 600,
    ...
    data:json,
    plugins: [
      {
        ...
      },
      {
        ...
      }]
  });  
}); 
});
```

It seems the error prompted because the lines below were removed however I tried to modify the code above to incorporate the code below but I got no luck to make it work. it seems these code is still needed in bubble-chart.js. I already checked my json strings and it is valid.

```
  eval: function (item) {return item.count;},
  classed: function (item) {return item.text.split(" ").join("");}
```

Is there anyone can help me solve this? any help would be appreciated. Thank you!
-Borj